# Why react new page render from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have multiple pages in my react project and, whenever I switch from one page to another the page position starts from the bottom but, I want to stay on top after rendering the page. I'm currently using router v5 and, I can't find any solution for router v5.

I've also tried another version solution but, It didn't work and could you please help me to solve this problem.

These are some of the examples I've tried so far but, not single ones have worked.

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  ...
</Router>
```

```
function handleUpdate() {
  let {
    action
  } = this.state.location;

  if (action === 'PUSH') {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}

...

<Router
  onUpdate={handleUpdate}
/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the solution I use to solve this problem.  Create a new component:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ScrollToTop = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return children || null;
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

and wrap your app contents in it INSIDE of the browser router

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ScrollToTop from './components/scroll-to-top/scroll-to-top';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop>
          <div />
        </ScrollToTop>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's giving me this error.

Attempted import error: 'useLocation' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: Ah then you should upgrade react-router, the hooks were added to it relatively recently

Comment: I just updated react-router library and also reinstalled node modules but still giving same error..

Comment: it needs to be version 5.1 not sure if thats what you updated to

Comment: @zee7, If upgrade is not an option, you can avoid using "useLocation". Change the code as below to use window.location.pathname instead as below: //const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const pathname = window.location.pathname; [http://www.clapself.com]

Comment: @KinshukSharma Your solution wouldn't help in this case, as the scrolling is triggered by a `useEffect` which only fires when a React state value changes.

Answer (score 3):

Create the next component:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);
  return null;
}
```

Import it in your index.js and use it before Switch component, like this:

```
  <ScrollToTop />
  <Switch>  
    ...
  </Switch>
```

And it should work.

Comment: It's giving me this error. Attempted import error: 'useLocation' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: @Taher I just updated react-router library and also reinstalled node modules but still giving same error..

Comment: @zee7 which version of react-router-dom are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The above methods of using `window.scrollToView(0, 0)` doesn't work for me. Thus, another workaround/solution which works for me is to have a `div` at the top with a `ref`. The `scrollIntoView` method would then be called in the `useEffect` hook to scroll the `div` into view on render.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const TestComponent = () => {
const topContainer = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // To make sure page starts from the top
  topContainer.current.scrollIntoView({ block: "end", behavior: 'smooth' });
  }, []);

return (
  <>
    <div ref={topContainer} />
    <div>Component to be rendered here</div>
  </>
  );
};
```

The property `behavior: 'smooth'` passed to `scrollIntoView` could be omitted too, if you do not want smooth animation of the scroll.

Comment: If you were referring to my answer, I used `window.scrollTo` not `window.scrollToView`.  Not sure if that was the issue you were having